# Emberjs's findAll not working with nested models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frontend

I have the following models:

```
App.MetadataItem = DS.Model.extend({
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  fieldName: DS.attr('string'),
  programMetadata: DS.belongsTo('programMetadata')
});

App.ProgramMetadata = DS.Model.extend({
  programId: DS.attr('number'),
  metadataItems: DS.hasMany('metadataItem')
});
```

And this is the response from my API:

```
[{
    "program_metadata": {
      "_id": "525c5ed50bdb82bb6a000001"
      "program_id": 6379,
      "metadata_items": [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "program_metadata": { ... }
  }]
```

I'm already dealing the problem with the id/_id and I can fetch a single record by overriding `extractSingle` method from my Serializer, but it's not working with `extractArray`. My code breaks when it reaches the `typeForRoot` method, it tries to use the array index as the type.
How should I build the array in the `extractArray`, given this API response?

Comment: Which version of ember-data do you use?

Comment: Ember-data 1.0 beta dropped support for complex responses, like one you have. Unless you restructure payload in extractArray this kind of responce will be failing. At first try to remove metadata_items from your response. Also as I remember ember-data expects something like {"program_metadatas":[{},{},{}]} If you are still interested I might have more for you tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just saw your answer today. I was using the latest version of ember-data, from builds.emberjs.com. I ended up writing the app with backbone, since most of my API responses were kind of inconsistent, making it hard to work with the ember data model.